# Can a redux immutable store contain a non immutable one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using redux with immutablejs.
We want to use a plugin that use redux internally but does not use immutablejs.

- This is how I create my app reducer:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable';

// prebuilt admin-on-rest features
import { adminReducer, localeReducer } from 'admin-on-rest';

// Initial routing state
const routeInitialState = fromJS({
  location: null,
});

/**
 * Merge route into the global application state
 */
function routeReducer(state = routeInitialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    case LOCATION_CHANGE:
      return state.merge({
        location: action.payload,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function createReducer(injectedReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer,
    admin: adminReducer, // <==== This reducer is not immutable
    // admin MUST be accessible using `(state) => state.admin` 
    // and NOT `(state) => state.get('admin')`
    locale: localeReducer(),
    form: formReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
  });
}
```

This is how I initiate the store:

```
const store = createStore(
  createReducer(),
  fromJS({}),
  composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
);
```

Only admin store should not be immutable.

Is it possible **admin** to plug that store as it is in our immutablejs store ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have plain javascript objects / arrays inside an immutable object (store), but you would need to be careful in how you work with the store. You would not be able to do `fromJS(store)`, because that would make the entire store immutable.

Comment: Would you write a custom `combienReducers` ? I have tried and it doesn't work pretty well.